# Integrating Internal Zoom (magiczoom) with Big Cartel

Tags: zooming, product, bigcartel, magiczoom

I've installed Magic Zoom in to my Big Cartel website, the zoom function works fine however the product is not actually zooming in?

http://www.generyanart.com/product/house-by-the-sea this is the website - I was just wondering what i needed to do to fix this issue, as i would like the zoom function to show the detail of the piece!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1: To zoom an image, one image has to be larger than the other. Your two images are the same size. Look carefully at the href and src here and you'll see they reference the same image:

```
`<a href="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/product_images/142875802/max_h-1000+max_w-1000/House-By-The-Sea-A32.jpg" class="MagicZoom" rel="zoom-width:450px; zoom-height:450px"><img src="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/product_images/142875802/max_h-1000+max_w-1000/House-By-The-Sea-A32.jpg" alt="Image of House By The Sea"/></a>`
```

Either make your main image (src) smaller in width/height or make your large image (href) bigger in width/height.

2: You must also fix some CSS. The following CSS rule in your stylesheet is reducing the zoom image to the width of the zoom window.

[image: CSS reference changing image width]

To display the image at its original (larger) size, add the following CSS:

```
.MagicZoomBigImageCont img { max-width:none !important; }
```

3: Not required, but because this particular image zoom is so large, it would look good enlarged to full-screen. That's possible [on click](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/#expand-size) if you use Magic Zoom Plus instead of Magic Zoom.